# plotly js Uncaught TypeError: myPlot.on is not a function

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I'm a newbie trying to learn.
I have modified the plot code at [plotly hover events](https://plotly.com/javascript/hover-events/#capturing-hover-events:-data)
The goal is to obtain hover events so that later I can show an image in a modal.

My CSV does read in, and the plot does show in the browser.
I get an error message: "Uncaught TypeError: myPlot.on is not a function" (in Firefox and Chrome debuggers).
Other posts on this issue indicate that I must be running the correct version of "https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js".
I have tried everything I can think of even making it linear code without multiple function calls.
Help!
Thanks...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
<div id="hoverinfo" style="margin-left:80px;"></div>
 
<script>
    var traces=[];
    var layout=[];
    var config={};
    var rows=[]
    const CSV="cloudcover.csv";

    Plotly.d3.csv(CSV, function(rows){
        let x=[];
        let y=[];
        let row;
        let i=0;
    while (i< rows.length){
        row=rows[i];
        x.push(row["Time"]);
        y.push(row["CloudCover"]);
        i+=1;
        };
    traces=[
        {x:x,
        y:y,
        line:{color:"#387fba"},
        width:2,
        }];

    layout={
        title:'Cloudcover',
        yaxis:{ range:[0,100]},
        xaxis:{tickformat: "%H:%M:%S"}
        };

    config={
        responsive:true
    };

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv',traces,layout,config,{showSendToCloud: true});
    });

    var myPlot = document.getElementById('myDiv')
    hoverInfo = document.getElementById('hoverinfo')

    myPlot.on('plotly_hover', function(data){
        var infotext = data.points.map(function(d){
          return (d.data.name+': x= '+d.x+', y= '+d.y.toPrecision(3));
        });
            hoverInfo.innerHTML = infotext.join('<br/>');
    })

     myPlot.on('plotly_unhover', function(data){
        hoverInfo.innerHTML = '';
    });
    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The csv is simple:

```
Time,CloudCover
2022-04-06 10:07:09,0
2022-04-06 11:07:18,100.0
2022-04-06 12:08:17,100.0
2022-04-06 13:09:16,96.0
2022-04-06 14:10:15,66.0
2022-04-06 15:11:14,7.0
2022-04-06 16:12:13,6.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put all of the plotly code inside the `Plotly.d3.csv` callback, including your event listener, like so:

```
Plotly.d3.csv(CSV, function (rows) {
        ...

        Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', traces, layout, config);

        const myPlot = document.getElementById('myDiv')

        myPlot.on('plotly_hover', function (data) {
            ...
        })

        myPlot.on('plotly_unhover', function (data) {
            ...
        });
});
```

This is because your data will only be available once the CSV file is loaded (i.e. you are inside the callback) and the `on` listener will only be available once the chart is created from the data.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Interesting way to organize the code, but once you see it, it makes sense.  Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Move the `Plotly.newPlot` out of the function passed to `Plotly.d3.csv`. Once `Plotly.newPlot` executes, it will insert the polyfills to allow listening to events using `.on(...)`

The below snippet plots a blank chart, it still doesn't have the `cloudcover.csv` file, but resolves your issue.

**Updated the snippet to use [Plotly.react()](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyreact)** to refresh data in the chart once the CSV content is available.
*Generally speaking, it's better to not have the component creation/rendering code within the data update function.*

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
<div id="hoverinfo" style="margin-left:80px;"></div>

<script>
  const chartEl = 'myDiv';
  const CSV = "cloudcover.csv";

  /*Create chart*/
  var layout = {
      title: 'Cloudcover',
      yaxis: {
        range: [0, 100]
      },
      xaxis: {
        tickformat: "%H:%M:%S"
      }
    },
    config = {
      responsive: true
    };

  Plotly.newPlot(chartEl, [], layout, config, {
    showSendToCloud: true
  });

  var myPlot = document.getElementById(chartEl)
  hoverInfo = document.getElementById('hoverinfo')

  myPlot.on('plotly_hover', function(data) {
    var infotext = data.points.map(function(d) {
      return (d.data.name + ': x= ' + d.x + ', y= ' + d.y.toPrecision(3));
    });
    hoverInfo.innerHTML = infotext.join('<br/>');
  })

  myPlot.on('plotly_unhover', function(data) {
    hoverInfo.innerHTML = '';
  });

  /*Update data in chart*/
  function updateChartData(rows) {
    let traces = [],
      x = [],
      y = [],
      row,
      i = 0;

    while (i < rows.length) {
      row = rows[i];
      x.push(row["Time"]);
      y.push(row["CloudCover"]);
      i += 1;
    };

    traces = [{
      x: x,
      y: y,
      line: {
        color: "#387fba"
      },
      width: 2,
    }];

    Plotly.react(chartEl, traces);
  }

  Plotly.d3.csv(CSV, updateChartData);
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The plot is empty, it appears that the globals of traces,layout,config are not being passed to: Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', traces, layout, config, {showSendToCloud: true }); The chrome debugger shows them as globals!!  The vars are declared in global scope.